# Stitching some images use JavaCV

Tags: opencv, image-processing, javacv

I use JavaCV to stitching images but the console outputs the following:

```
Finding features...
Features in image #1: 888
Features in image #2: 1483
Finding features, time: 0.523706 sec

Pairwise matching
1->2 matches: 456
1->2 & 2->1 matches: 485

.Pairwise matching, time: 0.14468 sec

Removed some images, because can't match them or there are too similar images: (2).

Try to decrease --match_conf value and/or check if you're stitching duplicates.

Need more images
```

This is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Stitcher stitcher = Stitcher.createDefault(true);

    MatVector images2 = new MatVector(2);

    images2.put(1, cvLoadImage("sample1.png"));
    images2.put(0, cvLoadImage("sample2.png"));

    IplImage result = new IplImage();


    int status = stitcher.stitch(images2, images2);

    result = cvLoadImage("sample1.png");

    final CanvasFrame canvas = new CanvasFrame("My Image", 1);


    canvas.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    // Show image on window.
    canvas.showImage(result);

}
```

They can Loadimage but didn't stitching images, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output is quite clear: "*Removed some images, because can't match them or there are too similar images: (2). Try to decrease `--match_conf` value and/or check if you're stitching duplicates.*"

Aren't your images too similar? If you are not sure about them, try to use the images available [here](http://ramsrigoutham.com/2012/11/22/panorama-image-stitching-in-opencv/). They should work.

And if it still doesn't work, investigate into `--match_conf`.

Comment: I changed images from http://ramsrigoutham.com/2012/11/22/panorama-image-stitching-in-opencv/ here. It's working but they produce other problem.
Like this:
 
Wave correcting...
Wave correcting, time: 4.82209e-005 sec
Warping images (auxiliary)...
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (k == MAT) in unknown function

what is problem at it ? thank you for help.